# How to get number's length in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

How could I get the length of a number in Dart? Is there an equivalent to the one used in strings?

For ex: 1050000 has a length of 7. How could I dynamically discover this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try this.

```dart
int i = 1050000;

int length = i.toString().length; // 7
// or
int length = '$i'.length; // 7
```

Comment: Short and sweet answer. This also works with decimal numbers, so 1050000.5 would return a length 9.

Comment: This dont work when a number start with 0, because toString() cut off leading 0

Answer (score 1):

With this extension method you would be able to use the length method on any number.

```
extension Num on num {
  int length() => this.toString().length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not precisely the question, but since I found this on my search for getting the magnitude and since I then copied the above answer without thinking:

If you want the magnitude of the number

```dart
extension Num on num {
  int length() => this.toInt().toString().length;
}
```